# Why I do not need to avoid SSL check but can request HTTPS resource when I use PHP cURL

Tags: php, ssl, curl, https

I use **curl** in PHP to request some https site such as `https://github.com`, and I use just code like this:

```
<?php 
   $ch = curl_init(); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://github.com/search?q=react"); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
   $output = curl_exec($ch); 

   echo $output;

   curl_close($ch);      
?>
```

Then, I can get the page.

But, I searched before and found that if requesting a **https** resource, it needs adding these codes:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```

So why I can request https resource without these two lines of codes to avoid SSL check?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need those 2 and probably don't want them

Comment: You don't need the `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` line either - a `GET` is default already. Don't use code without understanding what it does.

Answer (score 2):

The two Curl options are defined as:

> [CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html) - verify the peer's SSL certificate

and

> [CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST.html) - verify the certificate's name against host

They both default to `true` in Curl, and shouldn't be disabled unless you've got a good reason. Disabling them is generally only needed if you're sending requests to servers with invalid or self-signed certificates, which is only usually an issue in development. Any publicly-facing site should be presenting a valid certificate, and by disabling these options you're potentially opening yourself up to security issues.

Comment: OK, I got it. Thank you.